# how to get zipcode value without submitting form PHP variable?

Tags: php, ajax

get zipcode value without submitting form PHP variable?

```
<form>
    <input type="text" required name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your first name"  /><br><br>
    <span class="icon-contact-name"></span>
    <input type="text" required name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your last name" /><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" required placeholder="ZipCode"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: use javascript.

Comment: need value as php variable to run next. Any solution.

Comment: where do you want to get the zipcode from? this is just HTML code, there is nowhere you're trying to get any zipcode

Comment: i want the zip for 

 $zipcode;
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$zipcode."&sensor=false";
    $details=file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($details,true);

    $lat=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];

    $lng=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    
 echo "Latitude :" .$lat;
    //echo '<br>';
    echo "Longitude :" .$lng;
  //echo '<br>'; @PaulRoefs

Comment: You still need javascript. Look at AJAX calls

Comment: so if I understand right you want to use the zipcode to load the latitude and the longitude? if so you have to use javascript

Comment: @RST I do not think Ajax is the best way as it is not necessary to load a php file for this. This is not that hard to do using javascript/jquery

Comment: @PaulRoefs he specified 3 times he wants to use PHP.

Comment: @RST yes but using only PHP it is not possible, he has to use Javascript anyway, why not do it directly? What he wants is not possible so there is no more reason for him to avoid Javascipt.

Comment: if you have any solution please share it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript for this.
I did it using JQuery, you just have to add a div or span with the id 'lat-long'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#zipcode').keyup(function() {
    $.get( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + $('#zipcode').val() + '&sensor=false', function(data) {
      var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      $('#lat-long').html('Latitude: ' + lat + '<br />Longitude: ' + lng + '<br />')
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: how to call it in php

Comment: it is not possible using only in php, why do you need it in php?